# How to add use web view on a fragment file?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

How can I call a **WebView** on my fragment?
As you can see I have called it, but I am having an error. What I want to implement is a webpage to open on my application.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
package sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp;


import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class GeoNjoroFragment extends Fragment {


    public GeoNjoroFragment() {

        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_geo_njoro, container, false);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView)view.findViewById(sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp.R.id.webview);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;

    }



}
```

Here's an image of the error I'm receiving:

[image: Image of Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.
First of all you have to inflate your view and then use findViewById() method.
Add this permission **uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"** to Androidmanifest.xml file.

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_geo_njoro, container, false);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView)view.findViewById(sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp.R.id.webview);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.hivisasa.com/wb/nakuru/news/113249");
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
return view;
```

Comment: it working but on my android phone it displaying webpage not available what can be the reason(net;;ERR_CACHE_MISS)

Comment: I have tried it just see an update of the image on my post of the error i am having

Comment: @FrancisNdirangu Can't see image

Comment: IMAGE OF ERROR I AM HAVING click there

Comment: Have you added this <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET"/> in your manifest?. Also go to settings-> application manager, select your application and clear data and cache of your application in your device.

Comment: @FrancisNdirangu <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> also add this permissions to manifest.

Comment: it working now but it opening on browser  page it not opening on my layout   can you help please. How can i make to open on my layout

Comment: If you have written same code as you mentioned above then It should open in your WebView not in browser.

Answer (score 0):

U don't bind the view so that webview can't find the view to bind, it should be:

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_geo_njoro, container, false);
 WebView myWebView = (WebView)view.findViewById(sampleapp.razen.com.sampleapp.R.id.webview);

Comment: how do i open the html in my layout ??

Comment: if it's a static html string, you can do it by using e.g. textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(stringHtml)); if it's a url, pls use webview to do it.